# TypeError: cli.init is not a function using ReactNative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webstorm, apple-m1

I'm trying to set up my React Native environment on **Macbook Pro M1X** , Followed https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and still facing issues .

After creating a new project in **WebStorm** I get this Error :

```
TypeError: cli.init is not a function
    at run (/Users/mymac1/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:302:7)
    at createProject (/Users/mymac1/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:249:3)
    at /Users/mymac1/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:217:7
    at /Users/mymac1/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt.js:316:32
    at /Users/mymac1/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:142:25
    at assembler (/Users/mymac1/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt.js:313:9)
    at /Users/mymac1/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt.js:322:32
    at /Users/mymac1/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt.js:597:5
    at Interface.onLine (/Users/mymac1/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/read/lib/read.js:111:5)
    at Interface.emit (node:events:512:28)
```

I followed and installed :

1. Node & Watchman
2. Xcode + ajusted the Command Line Tools in Platforms + Installed iOS Simulators
3. Installed Ruby gem (CocoaPods) and later changed the version to 2.7.6 based on users suggestions

Tried to initiate a React Native project in terminal with : (version was suggested online / same issue with latest version as well )

```
 npx react-native init mnkn --version 0.68.2
```

and I was getting this error:

```
error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
Error: Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI
```

Got over this issue in terminal by using 'Yarn' used "yarn add expo" and then

```
 npx react-native init mnkn --version 0.68.2
```

worked (in terminal).

In WebStorm the same error (even with Yarn).

*I'm only starting out in JavaScript and React Native and my background is only Python and C.*

**Found no help online so I would Appreciate some help.**